# Insert Into Statement VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

Hi everyone I am coding in VBA using Access 2013 I wrote my code two different ways and keep getting a syntax error. Here's my code.

```
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
      CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO GroupVolunteers(Group, Leader, Name, 
phone, email, EmergencyContact, EmergencyContact) " & _
" VALUES(" & Me.txtGroup & "','" & Me.cboLeader & "','" & Me.txtName & "','"  
& Me.txtEmail & "','" & Me.txtPhone & "','" & Me.txtEmergencyContact & "','"
& Me.EmergencyNumber & "','" & Me.txtRegNumber & "')"

'clear form
cmdClear_Click
'refresh data in list on form
frmStudentSub.Form.Requery
End Sub
```

OR

```
'when we click on button Add there are two options
 '1. for insert
 '2. for update
 If Me.txtRegNumber & "" = "" Then
    'this is for insert new
    'add data to table
    CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO GroupVolunteers(Group, Leader, Name, 
   phone, email, EmergencyContact, EmergencyContact) " & _
            " VALUES(" & Me.txtGroup & "','" & Me.cboLeader & "','" &    
  Me.txtName & "','" & _
            Me.txtEmail & "','" & Me.txtPhone & "','" &   
    Me.txtEmergencyContact & "','" & Me.EmergencyNumber & "','" &_  
   Me.txtRegNumber & "')"
Else
'otherwise (Tag of txtID store the id of student to be modified)
 CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE GroupVolunteers " & _
      " SET Group=" & Me.txtGroup & _
            ", leader='" & Me.cboLeader & "'" & _
    ", name='" & Me.txtName & "'" & _
            ", email='" & Me.txtEmail & "'" & _
    ", phone='" & Me.txtPhone & "'" & _
    ", EmergencyContact='" & Me.txtEmergencyContact & "'" & _
            ", EmergencyNumber='" & Me.txtEmergencyNumber & "'" & _
            ", NumberVolunteers ='" & Me.txtNumberVolunteers & "'" & _
            " WHERE RegNumber = " & Me.txtRegNumber.Tag
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Can you describe the behavior you are trying to achieve and give some details about the error?

Comment: @SteveClanton with my else statement I keep receiving this error. Run-time error '3144': Syntax error in UPDATE statement and it highlights my whole else statement

Answer (score 3):

```
" VALUES(" & Me.txtGroup & "', ...
```

Think of how that's going to end up in your statement:

```
VALUES(<Me.txtGroup>', ...
```

In other words, you're either missing the opening quote for a character-type column or you have too many for a numeric-type column. It should be one of:

```
" VALUES('" & Me.txtGroup & "', ...  // for character-type column
" VALUES(" & Me.txtGroup & ", ...    // for numeric-type column
```

That should fix your `insert` in both code blocks, you may also want to examine the `update` in the second code block as well. It has no quotes on the `group` column which is okay if it's numeric-type but probably not if it's character-type.

Comment: just want to make sure I understand what you are saying. So it should be "Values(" " & Me.txtGroup &"',.......

Comment: @anecessa, sorry, should have been clearer, see the update with the added/removed quote (your previous comment appears to have a space which is not quite correct either).

Comment: thank you I appreciate your help. However now I receive an error in my else statement but I think I might be missing an opening quote now that I look at it again.